# Ubuntu install from USB stuck on black screen

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, plymouth, usb-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 from a bootable USB. I am new to using a Linux OS. I turned off fast boot option, and I left secure boot on (I also tried off, but then it's stuck on a blank screen rather than this). I have a Nvidia 880M if that is affecting anything.

I get stuck on this screen whether I choose "try Ubuntu without installing" or "install Ubuntu". This text is shown when I am stuck on the black screen.

[image: boot output screenshot]

Comment: Fastboot and Secure boot have to be off, secure boot is more critical to the system than fastboot.

Answer (score 7):

- Boot from USB drive and select <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>
- Press "**e**" and add

  ```
  nouveau.modeset=0
  ```

  to the **end of the linux line**.
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> - the Ubuntu USB installation media will boot without any issues now.

**Recommendation** to avoid running into the same problems with your new Ubuntu installation :

When rebooting after having finished the installation repeat the same procedure for starting the installed operating system -> ... select the **Ubuntu entry** from the **GRUB boot menu**, press "**e**" ...
After login to Ubuntu desktop first install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime 
sudo reboot
```

Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles** - switch to **NVIDIA** - log out and back in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after adding the nouveau.nomodeset, I would still be stuck on the splash screen with the same lines displayed in the image. I don't know if it is a persistent problem with the graphics driver or something else

Comment: Worked for Inspiron 15 7000 series Gaming Edition. Thanks

Comment: This works! My installation on the Dell Inspiron 15 5000 was freezing, until I did what you described. Magic!