# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install freezes on Dell 7559 Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, dell, laptop

Last night I tried to install the most recent version of Ubuntu on my Dell 7559 laptop as dual boot. I have a partition ready for the installation. When loading from USB drive made by Rufus, the splash screen comes up but just hangs there. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment due to lack of rep, so posting as an answer.

Refer to these answers,

1. [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
2. [Ubuntu install from USB stuck on splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683645/ubuntu-install-from-usb-stuck-on-splash-screen)

Does it help?

Comment: I know about the modoset when pressing 'e' but I never even get to that point. It just shows 'Ubuntu' with the 4 dots. 2 of the dots light up and then stops there.